# Make shape keep moving in direction in canvas until changed direction

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, but when I go left, right, up, or down, I can stop. I want to make it so it will keep going instead of me having to keep holding on the buttons. Look at the real version of snake to see what I'm talking about. I have already tried doing a while loop instead of and if statement, but that still didn't work. Please help if you can. Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Canvas</title>
    </head>
    <style>
     #canvas {
      outline:1px solid #000;
            background-color:black;
     }
    </style>
    <body>
    <input style="display:none;" id="score" type="text" name="score" value="0">            
    <br>
    <h2 id="h">Score: 0</h2>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="410" width="400"></canvas>
    <script>
     var box = 32;


     function reset() {
      location.reload();
     }
     var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

     var xPos = 10;
     var yPos = 10;
    
        var xPos2 = 90;
     var yPos2 = 90;
    
        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
     ctx.fillStyle = "#1aff1a";
     ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 20, 20);
    
        var ctx2 = c.getContext("2d");
     ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx2.fillRect(xPos2, yPos2, 20, 20);

     var d=0;
     function move(e){

  

      if(e.keyCode == 39){
       d="right";
      }
      if(e.keyCode == 37){
       d="left";
      }
      if(e.keyCode == 38){
       d="up";
      }
      if(e.keyCode == 40){
       d="down";
      }

      if(d=="right"){
       xPos += 10;
      }
      if(d=="left"){
       xPos -= 10;
      }
      if(d=="up"){
       yPos -= 10;
      }
      if(d=="down"){
       yPos += 10;
      }

      if (xPos == xPos2 && yPos == yPos2){
       score.value += "+";
       score.value += "1";
       score.value = eval(score.value);
       document.getElementById('h').innerHTML="Score: "+score.value;
       xPos2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 38) * 10;  
       yPos2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 38) * 10;
      } 

      if (xPos < 0 || xPos > 380){
          alert('you lost');
          alert('your score: '+ score.value)
          document.getElementById('canvas').style.display = "none";
         }
         if (yPos > 390 || yPos < 0){
      alert('you lost');
      alert('your score: '+ score.value)
      document.getElementById('canvas').style.display = "none";
         }

      canvas.width=canvas.width;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#1aff1a";
      ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 20, 20);
            ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx2.fillRect(xPos2, yPos2 , 20, 20);
     }
     function again(){
      if(d=="right"){
       xPos += 10;
      }
      if(d=="left"){
       xPos -= 10;
      }
      if(d=="up"){
       yPos -= 10;
      }
      if(d=="down"){
       yPos += 10;
      }
     }
     function win() {
      if (xPos == xPos2 && yPos == yPos2){
       alert('you win')
      } 
     }
     function while1(){
      while(d!="right" && d!="up" && d!="down" && d=="left"){
       xPos -= 10;
      }
      while(d=="right"){
       xPos += 10;
      }
      while(d=="up"){
       yPos -= 10;
      }
      while(d=="down"){
       yPos += 10;
      }
     }
     function block(){
      document.getElementById('score').style.display = "block";
     }
     while1()
     document.addEventListener("keydown", move);
    </script>
    <br><button style="width:200px; height:68px;" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to automate the movement of the green box (snake) you can use `requestAnimationFrame`, which takes the animation code that you want to iterate.

then you will need to save the previous `keyCode`, to update the movement direction.

for iterating the animation the code you put in `move` function need to be moved out in another function `iterate` which set the `requestAnimationFrame`, and when the `move` function is called again we need to `cancelAnimationFrame`, if you don't cancel animation frame, it will increase the animation frame speed every time `move` is called. bellow is the updated code that would solve you problem.

```js
var box = 32;

function reset() {
  location.reload();
}
var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var xPos = 10;
var yPos = 10;

var xPos2 = 10;
var yPos2 = 90;

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#1aff1a";
ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 20, 20);

var ctx2 = c.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
ctx2.fillRect(xPos2, yPos2, 20, 20);

var d = 0;
var hit;
var hitKey;
var animate;
var fps = 15;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000 / fps;
var delta;

function move(e) {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
  hitKey = e.keyCode;
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    d = "right";
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    d = "left";
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    d = "up";
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    d = "down";
  }
  again();
  iterate();
}

function iterate() {
  animate = requestAnimationFrame(iterate);
  now = Date.now();
  delta = now - then;

  if (delta > interval) {
    then = now - (delta % interval);
    if (xPos == xPos2 && yPos == yPos2) {
      score.value += "+";
      score.value += "1";
      score.value = eval(score.value);
      document.getElementById('h').innerHTML = "Score: " + score.value;
      xPos2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 38) * 10;
      yPos2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 38) * 10;
    }

    if (xPos < 0 || xPos > 380) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
      alert('you lost');
      alert('your score: ' + score.value)
      document.getElementById('canvas').style.display = "none";
    }
    if (yPos > 390 || yPos < 0) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
      alert('you lost');
      alert('your score: ' + score.value)
      document.getElementById('canvas').style.display = "none";
    }

    if (hitKey != hit) {
      canvas.width = canvas.width;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#1aff1a";
      ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 20, 20);
      ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx2.fillRect(xPos2, yPos2, 20, 20);
      again();
    }
  }
}

function again() {
  if (d == "right") {
    xPos += 10;
  }
  if (d == "left") {
    xPos -= 10;
  }
  if (d == "up") {
    yPos -= 10;
  }
  if (d == "down") {
    yPos += 10;
  }
}

function win() {
  if (xPos == xPos2 && yPos == yPos2) {
    alert('you win')
  }
}

function while1() {
  while (d != "right" && d != "up" && d != "down" && d == "left") {
    xPos -= 10;
  }
  while (d == "right") {
    xPos += 10;
  }
  while (d == "up") {
    yPos -= 10;
  }
  while (d == "down") {
    yPos += 10;
  }
}

function block() {
  document.getElementById('score').style.display = "block";
}
while1()
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  hit = e.keyCode;
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", move);
```

```css
#canvas {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input style="display:none;" id="score" type="text" name="score" value="0">
  <br>
  <h2 id="h">Score: 0</h2>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="410" width="400"></canvas>
  <br><button style="width:200px; height:68px;" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</body>

</html>
```

you can increase/decrease the speed of movement by changing `fps` value.

Comment: This did work, but is there anything simpler? I kind of lost you in the code.

Comment: `setInterval()` works similar to `requestAnimationFrame`, but that was not working fine for iterating logic, as for every repeat iteration again registers `setInterval()`, which incrementally increase movement speed, whereas in case of `requestAnimationFrame` we are canceling it every time (this way speed is kept constant).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set a `speed` variable. When you press a key, you change this `speed` variable accordingly.

And every frame, with a call `requestAnimationFrame`, you move the character according to the `speed` variable.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

const width = parseInt(canvas.width)
const height = parseInt(canvas.height)

const size = [10, 10] // the size of our object (a rectangle)
let speed = [0, 0] // the speed in x, and y
let topleft = [0, 0] // the top left corner of our rectangle


function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  context.fillStyle = 'red'
  context.fillRect(topleft[0], topleft[1], size[0], size[1])
  topleft[0] += speed[0]
  topleft[1] += speed[1]
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
    speed[0] -= 1
  } else if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') {
    speed[0] += 1
  } else if (e.code == 'ArrowUp') {
    speed[1] -= 1
  } else if (e.code == 'ArrowDown') {
    speed[1] += 1
  }
  e.preventDefault()
})

update()
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=640 height=400 />
</body>

</html>
```

Do you get the idea? We constantly update the canvas, *from* the speed variable. And we change the speed variable only when the user presses a key.